# How do I test an application with a global settings file?

Tags: unit-testing, python-3.x, testing, flask, global-variables

I am writing a Flask application and am in the process of writing tests. In my `foo/__init__.py`, I read a config file:

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from .conf import read_config    
settings = read_config()
```

I use `foo.settings` as a global object throughout my application, which makes testing very difficult.

For example:

```
import json
from foo import settings
from .helper import get_hosts_status

@app.route("/hosts/status")
def hosts_status():
    assert 'is_production' in settings
    data = {
        "num_hosts_up" : get_hosts_status(settings['is_production'])
    }
    return json.dumps(data)
```

In the above route, testing the code is very difficult because the `settings` object is imported from `foo`, making the code innately stateful. Since `settings` isn't a parameter to the function, I cannot simply mock the object.

I've been trying to refactor my application, but I cannot seem to avoid using some sort of globally scoped object like this. Is there an accepted way to test functions that rely on global objects like my `settings` object or is there a way to refactor this that makes it easier to test?

Comment: You could [`unittest.mock.patch.dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.patch.dict) it. Then you can replace specific keys or the whole thing.

Comment: @jonrsharpe That seems promising -- I'll take a look at that. Cheers for the resource!

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use Flask's native app.config.

If your settings are actually for the app itself, you can define multiple configs (prod, test, dev) in a config file, and based on where you load the app from you pick the config. Tests would use testing, production would read the config name production from env. var, and default would be dev.

Miguel Grinberg's Flask mega tutorial has it very well mapped out. Check out this repository (for his book, but his mega-tutorial works the same way):

- https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/config.py - shows example configs
- https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/tests/test_basics.py - shows how tests are calling the test config
- https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky/blob/master/app/__init__.py - shows how the app itself is created for deployment